# What information does a group extension Ext$^1(X,Y)$ convey?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-groups, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

I am struggling to understand exactly what a **group extension** is (Hartshorne is quite abstract for me). Studying vector bundles I encounter the following problem:

Let $X = P^1 ×P^1$ over the complex number be a quadric surface. We denote by $l$ and $m$ the standard basis of Pic$(X)=Z^2$. So, the canonical class $K_X =−2l−2m$ and $l^2=m^2=0$ and $lm=1$. Let $E$ be a rank 2 vector bundle on $X$ given by a non-trivial extension $e\neq 0$:
$$
0 \to O_X(l-3m) \to E \to O_X(3m) \to 0
$$
and

*apparently* this extension exists because 
$$ 
\text{Ext}^1(O_X(3m), O_X(l-3m)) \cong H^1(X,O_X(l-6m)) \cong \mathbb{C}^{10}
$$
My question is **is there a way to understand intuitively what information this group extension conveys?**

From the short exact sequence I know that gives the information that $O_X(l-3m) \backsimeq \frac{E}{O_X(3m)}$ but I do not know what else is hidden there. **How can I quickly compute $c_1(E)$ and $c_2(E)$?** And **how does this extension actually change $E$?**

Comment: Where is Hartshorne is the above example ? Or is it another source ?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are modules then $\text{Ext}^1(A,B)$ classifies the extensions of $B$ with quotient $A$, in other word how the middle spot in an exact sequence can be filled. So in your case I would guess that there is a 10 dimensional family of such vector bundles. Does that help ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus no it is not Hartshorne. I mention that I struggle to understand the Ext's from that book. And yes, the document I saw the above is the following lecture notes: http://www.dmi.unict.it/~pragmatic/docs/Pragmatic2009_RMMiroRoig-NotesModuliSpaces.pdf

Comment: @ReneSchipperus thanks a lot. It does not really help because in the example I give above the numbers $3m$ and $l-3m$ etc seem so arbitrary to me.

Comment: They are not numbers, they are lines on the quadric surface.

Comment: I know what they represent. I just want to say that I do not understand why the author pick the particular "twist" of the structure sheaf. Thanks for your comments. I still do not understand what the "extending proceedure" is or does to the vector bundle.

Comment: Yeah, why he chose those divisors, I cannot say, he is giving an example, and they make his example work, I guess if you better understood his goals and how the example works you would have more insight into the choice.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus do you know any reference where I can understand extensions of vector bundles specifically?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, there is a book, Vector Bundles of Curves. You might try that, I am not so familiar with it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not address the question of intuition, since most of the time it comes from understanding the technicalities. I do not know how much you know about extensions, so feel free to ask.

For vector bundles $E,F$ on a scheme $X$, $\mathrm{Ext}^i(E,F)=H^i(X,E^*\otimes F)$. In your case, thus, if $L,M$ are line bundles on $X$, $\mathrm{Ext}^1(L,M)=H^1(L^{-1}\otimes M)$. The Chern classes can be computed by Whitney sum formula. For any extension, $0\to M\to E\to L\to 0$, you have $c_1(E)=c_1(L\otimes M)$ and $c_2(E)=c_1(L)\cdot c_1(M)$. In particular, the Chern classes of $E$ do not depend on the extension, while the extensions may be very different.

Comment: Am I correct that $c_1(L ) \otimes c_1(M) = c_1(L) + c_1(M)$? My confusion with Ext groups is exactly their definition. I understand that the zeroth extension is the same as zeroth cohomology group which classifies global sections of the vector bundle, right? So, why do we need to extend $M$ by $L$ and why in the definition of the cohomology we tensor the inverse of $L$ with $M$? Sorry if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Ext is the derived functor of Hom and $H^i$ is the derived functor of $H^0$. Yes, $c_1(L\otimes M)$ (not $c_1(L)\otimes c_1(M)$) is $c_1(L)+c_1(M)$, depending on where you calculate Chern classes. For two vector bundles $E,F$, $\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)=H^0(E^*\otimes F)$, so at least it is conceivable (needs a proof) that the derived functors are the same for these two functors. We do not NEED to extend as above, but they come naturally and sometimes, they help you understand larger rank bundles in terms of smaller rank bundles.

Comment: I am sorry, the above comment got a bit garbled, due to my carelessness.

Comment: Thanks. My category theory is rusty but here is how I get it. If we have a category with objects being sheaves $E,F$ then the morphisms are group homomorphisms (for example) given by $Hom(E,F):E \to F$. So, when people write that this map is the same as $H^0(E^*\otimes F)$, that is a global section of this tensor bundle, I get really confused. I cannot understand why this is true. Then, I do not know what a derived functor is (I know naively what the derived category is though). Could you, if you dont mind, expand a little bit more your answer? Thanks :)

Comment: This can not be answered here, since it will take up too much space and time. I suggest you read them up to your satisfaction.

Comment: @Mohan Do you happen to know where I could find a proof for $\mathrm{Ext}^i(E,F)=H^i(X,E^*\otimes F)$?